# Does a seatpost affect the rigidity of the frame?

Tags: seatpost

Is it possible to use a zero offset seatpost to make the bike frame more rigid?

I consider the Crank Brothers Cobalt 1 Straight Seatpost.

Comment: i think an offset post might flex a little more than an otherwise equivalent straight post. is that what you mean?

Comment: Even if you assume the straight seatpost is more rigid, that doesn't mean the seatpost and frame together will be more rigid - the frame might just flex more as loads get transferred through the seatpost instead of being absorbed in greater seatpost flex.  The only real way to know is to actually do dynamic load testing of the bike with both types of seatposts and compare the results.  For what it's worth, I suspect that if you actually did such testing you wouldn't notice significantly different results unless there is a noticeable difference in the seatposts themselves.

Comment: (cont) Setback vs. straight for similar seatposts will almost certainly make no difference.  If your current setback seatpost is a flimsy wet noodle, that's the problem, not the fact that it's a setback seatpost.

Comment: Hi Paul H,

I mean that I want to do my bicycle stiffer with straight seatpost. Also, I have some pain in back during long time riding.

Answer (score 5):

Seatpost setback is used to get the saddle in the right place to get proper rider fit on the bike. The amount of setback required is dictated by the desired riding position, the seat tube angle and the bottom bracket to saddle distance.

If you switch out a seatpost that has some setback for one without you are either going to mess up your riding position or be forced to mount your saddle to far rearward in the rail clamps.

Comment: Agreed - if the frame is noodley (noodly?) then no amount of money spent on seatposts will help.